# Insert content from another site's table into my form using AJAX/PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, websocket

My question begins below this paragraph: I have a form containing an input where someone can enter a permit number (i.e. '121640466') and once an adjacent button is clicked, a new browser tab takes you to a site that contains all of that permit's information in a tabular format:

```
$(".bis_button").click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).parent('.frm_form_field').find('input').val();
    window.open('http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber='+inputValue+'&passdocnumber=&go10=+GO+&requestid=0');
});
```

Now, my question has several components to it that I'm hoping can help someone point me in the direction of what I'm looking to achieve:

**What I essentially want is to allow someone to enter a permit number, and once an adjacent link is clicked, multiple specific fields in my *form* are populated with specific content from the site containing the *table*.**

Let's use [this](http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/JobsQueryByNumberServlet?passjobnumber=121640466&passdocnumber=&go10=%20GO%20&requestid=0) page (we'll call it "permit page") that contains a permit's information to show what the process would look like. For this example, let's extract the *Borough* (Manhattan) from the table w/ heading *Location Information (Filed At)*:

1. On my form, enter permit number 121640466 into `<input id="field_cao2yl">`
2. On "permit page", Find `<table>` that contains `<td>` w/ content "Borough" and copy the content of the next adjacent `<td>` (in this case, the content is "Manhattan")
3. On my form, insert "Manhattan" into `<input id="field_qeu829">`

I'm hoping that this can be done with AJAX and PHP so that the page doesn't have to be refreshed to have the information from "permit page" inserted into my form's inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Accept the input from the user in your page
2. Pass it to a PHP script using AJAX and retrieve the value in your PHP script
3. Parse the required information using an HTML parser like [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).
4. Send back the results to client
5. Populate your form fields with the values.

Comment: Thank you for the response Amal. I'll start looking into this type of solution. With 4 & 5, how would those be accomplished?

Comment: @EricMatthewTurano: Many [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+get+ajax+data) questions have been asked here on StackOverflow. You may want to check some of them out. It'll give you a good idea how things are done. If you are stuck, feel free to ask a new question.